# Javascript - Convert a datetime, knowing its time zone, to UTC

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, datetime-conversion, ecmascript-temporal

I must convert a date time, given its time zone, year, month, day, hours and minutes to an ISO string.

For example, given the following parameters:

```
{
 timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
 year: 2020,
 month: 11,
 day: 18,
 hours: 14,
 minutes: 44,
}
```

I want to build the ISO string corresponding: `2020-11-18T13:44:00.000Z` (notice the hour shift there)

You can do this the other way around pretty easily, either with the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` or the  `toLocaleDateString`/`toLocaleTimeString` methods, but this way I can't find a proper solution...
If I overlooked any source of information, please let me know.

EDIT (see comments):

The perk of using a time zone and not a GMT string, such a `'GMT +01:00'`, is that I won't have to handle time changes. As you may know, the time zone `'Europe/Paris'` is `'GMT +01:00'` in the winter but `'GMT +022:00'` in the summer... And I can't find a proper way to map the timezone to any UTC offset

Thank you in advance for your help

**SOLUTION**:

As suggested below, using Luxon we can do

```js
const timeObject = { day, month, year, hours, minutes, zone: timeZone };
const date = DateTime.fromObject(timeObject).toUTC().toString();
```

Matt also suggested the for now experimental [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) feature.

Comment: What about all the UTC methods on the Date prototype? And `.toUTCString()`?

Comment: I cannot use this methods as i cannot set the timezone. The server executing this code is to UTC 0, so any "new Date()" instructions will return an unconverted date time. I will get a unshifted ISO string (eg: 2020-11-18T14:44:00.000Z instead of 2020-11-18T13:44:00.000Z)

Comment: Your question says that you have the time zone information ("Europe/Paris").

Comment: If you can map the string time zone information to an offset, you can build your own ISO string that includes the offset. Then you can extract the constructed UTC version.

Comment: That is exactly my point. The perk of using a timeZone and not a GMT string (such a GMT +01:00) is that I won't have to handle time changes. As you may know, the timeZone 'Europe/Paris' is GMT +1 in the winter but GMT +2 in the summer... And I can't find a proper way to map the timezone to any offset

Comment: Well you could look into using Moment, which allows for a locale database that's extendable if necessary.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using Moment.js as it starts being deprecated... Thank you for the help anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) (the successor to Moment).

```js
// your input object
const o = {
  timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
  year: 2020,
  month: 11,
  day: 18,
  hours: 14,
  minutes: 44,
};

// create a Luxon DateTime
const dt = luxon.DateTime.fromObject({
  year: o.year,
  month: o.month,
  day: o.day,
  hour: o.hours,
  minute: o.minutes,
  zone: o.timeZone
});

// convert to UTC and format as ISO
const s = dt.toUTC().toString();

console.log(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.25.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, you could simplify if your input object used the same field names as Luxon needs.

Comment: Note, this scenario will be better handled by [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) if and when it is eventually incorporated into the JavaScript language standard.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is what I ended to do, in two lines... I've updated my question. Temporal looks very interesting to! Thank you again for the info

Answer (score 2):

When [Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) is available in your browser engine (or if you use a [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal#polyfills)) then just do this:

```js
Temporal.ZonedDateTime.from({
  timeZone: 'Europe/Paris',
  year: 2020,
  month: 11,
  day: 18,
  hour: 14,
  minute: 44,
}).toInstant().toString();
// => '2020-11-18T13:44:00Z'
```

Answer (score -1):

here is my answer:

```
    var year = 2020;
    var month = 11;
    var day = 18;
    var hours = 14;
    var minutes = 44;
    var string = years + month + day + hours + minutes;
```

if you want to display the string on output:

```
    var year = 2020;
    var month = 11;
    var day = 18;
    var hours = 14;
    var minutes = 44;
    var string = years + month + day + hours + minutes;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "time in string" + 
    string
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, I want the ISO string to be converted to UTC time. You do not handle the time zone here.